# React Bootstrap issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

The grid system don't work maybe i'm dumb but i don't understand, my code :

```
import React from "react";
import {Col, Row} from "react-bootstrap";


const Home = () => {
    return (
            <Row className="home">
                <Col xs={6}>2 of 3 (wider)</Col>
                <Col xs={6}>3 of 3</Col>
            </Row>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: What doesn't work, and how does it not work? Please clarify what your actual issue is.

Comment: I do the npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap@5.1.3 and that but nothing happend the second Col is in  another line the only thing i put in css is the length of the Row

Comment: Without more context, as @EmilKarlsson said, we can't help you. This might help : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I can show you my App.js : 

`import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Home from "./component/Home/Home";

function App() {
  return (
    <Home />
  );
}

export default App;`

Comment: If Mani Yeganeh's answer didn't fix your problem, I'll say what I said again: we can't help you without more context. What's the content of `className=home`? Why aren't your `Row` and `Col` contained inside a `<Container>` as the docs suggests? Why did you put `xs` values and no `sm` or `lg` values?  What does your current code shows on screen? Is there any error/warning? That's all part of the context. You're basically asking: "I have a problem with my computer, fix it please".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should import bootstrap css in your project

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the `bootstrap CDN link`  in the **index.html** in the public folder.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Reference https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/

Comment: You can click on plus vote or green tick